# Removing entities from Collection in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm trying to manually delete every entity that's in a collection on an entity. The problem is, the entities don't get deleted from the database, even though they get removed from the collection on the task.

Below is the code im using to achieve this:

```
public int removeExistingCosts(final DataStoreTask task) {

    int removedAccumulator = 0;
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(DataStoreCost.GET_COSTS_FOR_TASK);
    query.setParameter(DataStoreCost.TASK_VARIABLE_NAME, task);


    try {

        List costsForTask = query.getResultList();
        for(Object cost : costsForTask) {
            task.getCosts().remove(cost);
            removedAccumulator++;
        }

    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        logger.debug("Couldn't costs for task: {}", task.getId());
    }

    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.persist(task);

    return removedAccumulator;
}
```

Any ideas?

P.S the collection is represented as:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DataStoreCost.class, mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<DataStoreCost> costs;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not deleting the entity, because it doesn't know if something else is referring to it.

You need to enable delete orphan.  In jpa2, use the [orphanRemoval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/index.html) attribute.  If you're using hibernate annotations, use CascadeStyle delete orphan.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly remove the `Cost` entity via the `entityManager`. When you remove the `Cost` from the `Tasks` cost list you actually only remove the reference to that instance. It does not know that that particular `Cost` will not be used anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, call `entityManager.remove(cost);` in the for loop.